# Python print out initial

Tags: python

I know it is a pretty simple question. I just want to know if there are some fast approaches to complete this sample. I need to generate initials like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5 :
        print('********')
    else:
        print('*      *')
```

And, the graph should be:

```
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
********
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
```

Basically, like printing a letter like this. What if I need to generate millions of this? What should be the optimization toward this question? I hope some of you could help me.

Comment: What code have you tried? Have you managed to print out other shapes?

Comment: Why are you finding this harder than any of the other letters you've printed out?  What part of the program is giving you trouble?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry. I just want to know if there are some fast approaches to complete this sample.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that SO is not a code-writing service, though.

Comment: OK. I apologize. And I hope you can understand my original intention as I mentioned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also do it non-iteratively:

```
print('\n*      *'*4)
print('********')
print('*      *\n'*4)
```

It works by printing 2 stars and a newline everytime, and then the series of stars, and then another row of 2 stars (with newline as well).

This prints out:

```
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
********
*      *
*      *
*      *
*      *
```

as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Something, like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    if i == 5 :
        print('********')
    else:
        print('*      *')
```